# getting control information does not work properly in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform containing these controls :

[winform controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y3I2.jpg)

I want to extract the information about controls like panels and buttons in the panel and panels in the panels and so on , and it is important to get info about nested controls.

here is my code [MainFrm.cs ] :

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace TestExpoter
    {
        public partial class MainFrm : Form
        {
            public MainFrm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private StringBuilder _sbtmp = new StringBuilder();
            private void okbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (Control c in Controls)
                {
                    if (c.GetType() == typeof (Panel))
                    {
                       enumerate_panel_child_contols((Panel)c);
                    }

                }

                MessageBox.Show(@"done");
            }
            private void enumerate_panel_child_contols(Panel pnl)
            {
                _sbtmp.Clear();

                foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
                {
                    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                    {
                        _sbtmp.AppendLine("ButtonName=>" + c.Name);
                    }
                    else if (c.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
                    {
                        enumerate_panel_child_contols((Panel)c);
                        _sbtmp.AppendLine("PanelName=>" + c.Name);
                    }
                }
                var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\" + pnl.Name  + ".txt");
                sw.WriteLine(_sbtmp.ToString());
                sw.Close();
                _sbtmp.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

[MainFrm.Designer.cs]:

```
    namespace TestExpoter
    {
        partial class MainFrm
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.okbtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.panel0 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
                this.button0 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
                this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.panel0.SuspendLayout();
                this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // okbtn
                // 
                this.okbtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(335, 67);
                this.okbtn.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
                this.okbtn.Name = "okbtn";
                this.okbtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(74, 31);
                this.okbtn.TabIndex = 2;
                this.okbtn.Text = "OK";
                this.okbtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.okbtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.okbtn_Click);
                // 
                // panel0
                // 
                this.panel0.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
                this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.button0);
                this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.label2);
                this.panel0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 33);
                this.panel0.Name = "panel0";
                this.panel0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 121);
                this.panel0.TabIndex = 0;
                // 
                // button0
                // 
                this.button0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 49);
                this.button0.Name = "button0";
                this.button0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(83, 26);
                this.button0.TabIndex = 0;
                this.button0.Text = "button0";
                this.button0.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // panel1
                // 
                this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
                this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(146, 32);
                this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
                this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 64);
                this.panel1.TabIndex = 3;
                // 
                // button1
                // 
                this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 18);
                this.button1.Name = "button1";
                this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 23);
                this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.button1.Text = "button1";
                this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                // 
                // label1
                // 
                this.label1.AutoSize = true;
                this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 15);
                this.label1.Name = "label1";
                this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 15);
                this.label1.TabIndex = 3;
                this.label1.Text = "panel0";
                // 
                // label2
                // 
                this.label2.AutoSize = true;
                this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(143, 14);
                this.label2.Name = "label2";
                this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 15);
                this.label2.TabIndex = 4;
                this.label2.Text = "panel1";
                // 
                // MainFrm
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(430, 179);
                this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
                this.Controls.Add(this.panel0);
                this.Controls.Add(this.okbtn);
                this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ((byte)(178)));
                this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
                this.Name = "MainFrm";
                this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                this.Text = "Form1";
                this.panel0.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.panel0.PerformLayout();
                this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.PerformLayout();

            }

            #endregion

            private System.Windows.Forms.Button okbtn;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel0;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button button0;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;

        }
    }
```

the output files are 2 text file : panel0.txt , panel1.txt

and panel0.txt contains :
PanelName=>panel1
ButtonName=>button0

and panel1.txt contains :
ButtonName=>button1

that is what I want , but the problem is that when the order of child controls in the panel changes, these outputs show wrong info :

if I change the order of panel0 child controls from :

```
        this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.button0);
        this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.label2);
```

to :

```
           this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.button0);
           this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
           this.panel0.Controls.Add(this.label2);
```

so the output will be :
panel0.txt contains :
PanelName=>panel1

and panel1.txt contains :
ButtonName=>button1

that is wrong.
why this happended and how should I fix this ?
thanks.

**[update1]:**
due to the answer of D. Petrov , if I remove the _sbtmp.Clear(); from the first row in the  enumerate_panel_child_contols , it will be :

```
             private void enumerate_panel_child_contols(Panel pnl)
            {
                foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
                {
                    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                    {
                        _sbtmp.AppendLine("ButtonName=>" + c.Name);
                    }
                    else if (c.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
                    {
                        enumerate_panel_child_contols((Panel)c);
                        _sbtmp.AppendLine("PanelName=>" + c.Name);
                    }
                }
                var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\" + pnl.Name  + ".txt");
                sw.WriteLine(_sbtmp.ToString());
                sw.Close();
                _sbtmp.Clear();
            }
```

but there is another problem and the output will be : 
panel0.txt contains :
PanelName=>panel1

and panel1.txt contains :
ButtonName=>button0
ButtonName=>button1

that is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisWohlert : I changed the order of adding controls in the mainform not in the designer file. i am looking for a general solution.

Comment: Yeah, I realised short after commenting. :)

Comment: @ChrisWohlert : no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mainly with this row at the beginning of the `private void enumerate_panel_child_contols(Panel pnl)`:

```
_sbtmp.Clear();
```

Because as you can see, with the second order of the controls shown you have the button BEFORE your panel. And with the code you have:

```
private void enumerate_panel_child_contols(Panel pnl)
        {
            _sbtmp.Clear();

            foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    _sbtmp.AppendLine("ButtonName=>" + c.Name);
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
                {
                    enumerate_panel_child_contols((Panel)c);
                    _sbtmp.AppendLine("PanelName=>" + c.Name);
                }
            }
            var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\" + pnl.Name  + ".txt");
            sw.WriteLine(_sbtmp.ToString());
            sw.Close();
            _sbtmp.Clear();
        }
```

You're actually writing the button info into the streamwriter once (becuase it's before the panel) and then, as you reach the pannel, you're clearing your StringBuilder again and write the info of the panel. That's why you have only the info of the panel if you put the button above it in the list.

The problem occurs mainly beacuse you're using the same StringBuilder with two different sets of data (for two different files). You should rethink your algorhytm a bit, it's not hard to reach.

***[update1]***

A simple enough solution of this problem is just to create the stringbuilder for each single execute of the void and not make it global. All the problems should be gone, since there will be no such overwriting of the same global stringbuilder anymore.

```
public partial class MainFrm : Form
{
    public MainFrm()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }


    void okbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof (Panel))
            {
                enumerate_panel_child_contols((Panel)c);
            }

        }

        MessageBox.Show(@"done");
    }

    void enumerate_panel_child_contols(Panel pnl)
    {
        StringBuilder _sbtmp = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                _sbtmp.AppendLine("ButtonName=>" + c.Name);
            }
            else if (c.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
            {
                enumerate_panel_child_contols((Panel)c);
                _sbtmp.AppendLine("PanelName=>" + c.Name);
            }
        }

        using(var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\" + pnl.Name  + ".txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(_sbtmp);
            sw.Close();
        }

        _sbtmp.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question based on your answer because i can not post all of them in the comment part. thanks.

Comment: The logic of your code is generally wrong. I advised you to rethink the use of the same StringBuilder, that's what mixes the stuff up. With the code now, as soon as you reach the panel1 in the controls of panel0, you begin to assing the controls of panel1 to the stringbuilder with the button that's left from panel0. And just at the end, as you write it down, you clear the stringbuilder and afterwards you print the info that panel1 is present in panel0, because you've finished writing panel1.txt already. I'll give you an example.

Comment: thanks alot. I am waiting for your example and your help to solve this problem.

Comment: Updated my answer. Problem not so complicated at all.